# (Re-)Install Chrome Desktop App Launcher on OS X Yosemite

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I have the latest version of `Chrome (43.0.2357.124 (64-bit)` installed on my MacBook running OS X 10.10.3. Somehow I lost the Desktop `App Launcher` and I need it back. I've exhausted Google search.

How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Chrome, use the URL chrome://flags/ to access experimental settings, enable the "Reset the App Launcher install state on every restart." setting. Restart Chrome.

You should now have the app launcher in your dock (Well, at least that what happened to me.)

You will now want to disable the experimental setting.

This worked for me with a Chrome version of Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) on Mac OSX 10.11.1 (Not Yosemite sorry, but hopefully same solution works)

Comment: I always forget about the experimental flags. This worked for me as well. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

Bad news!  Launcher has been given the axe in the last few days...

http://www.engadget.com/2016/03/22/chrome-app-launcher-dead/

Turns out it was a resource hog and has been axed.  I only discovered this as I created a new user on my Mac and suddenly the new user account couldn't access said launcher.  Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this support page](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?p=cws_app_launcher&rd=1) you'll get the app launcher when you install a Chrome app. So install something like [Hangouts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl).

If that doesn't do it, then further down that same support page, it says this:

> 1. Go to **Finder** and type "App Launcher" in the search box. You can also use the Spotlight search box at the top right of your screen.
> 2. Drag the App Launcher icon to your Dock.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I tried all that. Finder finds nothing and installing new apps doesn't reinstall anything.

Comment: That's important information to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If App Launcher doesn't show in Spotlight, it's most likely gone for good. All the above didn't work for me either, but I found out you can just go here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher

and install it.